# No output on web page PHP while executing shell command

Tags: php, linux, shell, asterisk

I am trying to execute Linux shell command from php but there is no output on web page. If I am trying to execute the php page from linux cosole its working fine.

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
    $result = shell_exec('asterisk -rx "core show channels concise"');
    $ccount =shell_exec('asterisk -rx "core show channels count"');
    echo $result;
    echo $ccount;
?>
```

Above code is not giving any output on web page. But on linux console its woking. e.g.

> [abc@host sysadminman]# php myfile.php

Comment: Maybe the apache user doesn't have permission. Whats the error log show?

Comment: you need to locate the executable path in a shell_exec call. for example /usr/bin/asterisk -rw "core show channels concise"

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk control socket permissions can also be changed easily in */etc/asterisk.conf*:

```
[files]
astctlpermissions = 0660
astctlowner = root
astctlgroup = apache
astctl = asterisk.ctl
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is incomplete as you not showing what is expected output. But aside from this you are doing a few common mistakes there.
First you are testing your script as root (`# php ...`) but your httpd is NOT serving your scripts as root. So your tests are useless. You should switch to right user (most likely `www-data` and then check to run your script from shell. Most likely it will fail for one of two common reasons - insufficient permissions to run `asterisk` program or incomplete `$PATH` not pointing to the place where `asterisk` is.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to Marcin.

I would suggest you write script to execute those commands and put result to some storage (such as text or database). Use cron to run it in root. Then you read the data from storage on web page.

If you want real time response, you have to run cron all the time though it consume server resource. That is trade-off you have to consider. Its depends on what you wanna achieve from the web site.

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo to run thoes commands as root or Asterisk user. You can configure sudo to allow execution without password to only specific commands.

Answer (score 0):

check `disable_functions` in `php.ini`. Mb shell_exec just off for web server